# What is the default z-index value of html elements?

Tags: html, css

How are multiple HTML-Elements stacked, when there is no `z-index` defined?

Is there any default value specified for different tags?

Answer (score 1):

The default value would be the order of appearance, see: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 1):

Since the [`z-index`-property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) only works on positioned elements (`position: absolute|relative|fixed`), it does not have a default value without further styling.

The default value when positioned is `z-index: auto` which is similar to `z-index: 0`.

If you had multiple positioned elements with `z-index: auto` or `z-index: 0` they would be stacked according to the ([W3C CSS2 specification on stacking context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html#painting-order)):

> All positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto' or 'z-index: 0', in tree order.

Which means the order that is defined in the document with the last element being the highest stacked:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

when no `z-index` is provided the default stack order is used.. elements down the stack order will appear on top..